# storing values in the markup for using in javascript (not xhtml compliant)

Tags: javascript, xhtml

sometimes i store values in the element's atributes for using in javascript.

ex: `<div class="open_popup" target="first_popup">click here</div>`.

also, some javascript plugins that i use put elements in the page with the atribute `generated="true"`.

it is a very useful technique for me but it is not compliant with the strict versions of xhtml.

what problems should it cause?
should i worry about that?
if i should, what's the solution?

thanks (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use the [jQuery.data](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) method:

```
// attach ('foo', 52) to the key/value store for the document.body element
jQuery.data($('#id_of_your_element'), 'foo', 52);
```

The problems with your method, at least the way I see it, is that it is not valid xhtml. And why would that matter? Basically, you don't know exactly how a browser would handle your invalid attributes - it might just strip them off the dom node or something else completely.

Comment: yes. that is exactly the problem. your solution is very nice! but it requires me to select each element and atatch data to it. i wanted to create the functions with jquery and simply use the markup to control the behavior...

Comment: this link is awesome. there's a lot of useful compliant techniques! thank you very much!